# Error when passing id from one component to another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Am trying to pass a button's id from this `ProductList.js` to `Cart.js`. The problem is that it works well in the `ProductList.js` where the function is defined. When it gets `Cart.js` component, there is an error.

`ProductList.js`

```
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react'
import Cart from "./Cart"

const ProductList = ({products}) => {

    let [pid, setPid] = useState()

    const cartRef = useRef()

    function btnID(e) {
        pid = e.target.id
        setPid(pid)
        cartRef.current.btnClick();   
        
    }

    return (

        <div className="row">
            <Cart ref={cartRef} pid={pid}/><br/><br/>
            {products.map((product) => (
            //    <ProductItem product={product} onClick={() => cartRef.current.btnClick()}/>
               <>
                    <div className="col-md-4">
                        <div className="card">
                        <Link href="/product/[id]" as={`/product/${product.id}`}>
                            <img className="card-img-top" src="" alt="" height="180px" style={{backgroundColor:"lightgray"}}/>
                        </Link>
                            <div className="card-body">
                                <h6 className="card-title">{product.title}</h6> 
                                <b><h3 class="card-text float-start">${product.price}</h3></b><br/><br/>
                                <button class="btn btn-outline-primary w-100 pid" onClick={btnID} id={product.id}>Add to cart</button>
                            </div>
                        </div><p></p>
                    </div>
                </>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}


export default ProductList
```

`Cart.js`

```
import { getDisplayName } from "next/dist/shared/lib/utils"
import react, {useState, forwardRef, useImperativeHandle} from "react"

const Cart = ({pid}, ref) => {
    
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
    // const [vcount, vsetCount] = useState(setCount)

    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
        btnClick
    }))

    function btnClick() {
        console.log(pid)
        setCount(count + 1 )
    }
         
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <button className="btn btn-outline-primary" style={{float:"right", display:"inline-block"}}>Cart ({count})</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default forwardRef(Cart)
```

The `btnID` function in `ProductList.js` gets the id of the button clicked and then passes it to `btnClick` function in `Cart.js`. The issue is when the id gets to `Cart.js` and it is console logged it shows `undefined` before displaying the id when the button is clicked again.

[Click here to see erroe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTNSv.png)

Comment: That's because state updates are asynchronous. That means by the time you are logging your state hasn't been fully updated yet. You should log *after* a state changes with a `useEffect` hook.

Comment: Alternatively use the sources tab to step through your code and not rely on console.logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with [@Emiel Zuurbier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11619647/emiel-zuurbier)

Updates are asynchronous, so the `undefined` output is not an error, but the previous `pid` state prior to it being updated. Use `useEffect` with `pid` in this case, i.e.:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (pid) console.log(pid)
}, [pid])
```

Also, should avoid direct assignment of `pid` value on line `pid = e.target.id` within `btnID` method by renaming the variable or setting the `pid` value using `setPid(e.target.id)` directly and recommend `pid` to a `const` to avoid such issues.